# Pyspark delete row from PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, psycopg2, sql-delete

How can PySpark remove rows in PostgreSQL by executing a query such as `DELETE FROM my_table WHERE day = 3` ?

SparkSQL provides API only for inserting/overriding records. So using a library like `psycopg2` could do the job, but it needs to be explicitly compiled on the remote machine, that is not doable for me. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that works so far is to install `psycopg2` to spark master node and call queries like a regular python would do. Adding that library as py-files didn't work out for me

Answer (score 0):

Dataframes in Apache Spark are immutable. You can filter out the rows you don't want.

See the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.sql).

A simple example could be:

```sql
df = spark.jdbc("conn-url", "mytable")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("mytable")
df2 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE day != 3")
df2.collect()
```

Comment: I need literally to delete records in that table

Comment: You can write that dataframe back to the table using `mode=overwrite`. Is that acceptable for your use case? Otherwise, unfortunately you cannot do what you want with Spark. You'll need to open a regular JDBC connection.